# What is the Difference between Linear programming optimization and a gradient descent optimization?

Tags: math, statistics

In linear programming problem we formulate two linear functions and an optimization function. where we find points where the two linear functions intersect and substitute these values in the optimization function to get the max or min.

How is this different from a gradient decent optimization. Can anybody elaborate on this mathematically. Are both methods reaching the global maximum or minimum? which is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- linear programming finds the weights that optimize that linear combination. it is *guaranteed* to work, but *only works* for functions that are linear combinations
- gradient descent can work on *any function*, as long as you know its derivative. However, it is only guaranteed to work if the function is convex. Otherwise it will get stuck at a local optimum

So, there's really no choice. If you have a linear combination, linear programming is better. In every other case, gradient descent is your only option.

Comment: Is there any other optimization technique other than the one I mentioned.

Comment: @user10573543: depends on the problem. in most problems however, variants of gradient descent are used. there is no general optimization methods that is guaranteed to work. that's one of the biggest problems in all engineering