# Optimized machine learning technique

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Question: I'm looking for a technique that I can use to reduce the number of iterations my application has to perform to find the optimal variable combination out of all possible variable combinations without testing every variable combination.

Current situation: I have a list of variables and each variable has a valid list of values. At the moment I'm creating a cartesian product of the list of valid variable values and I run logic across each possible variable combination. This means I'm wanting to run 2 000 000 different iterations and this takes a lot of time. I'm not interested in how to more efficiently run 2 000 000 different variable combinations but, instead after a technique I could use to hone in on an optimal variable combination without running through all the combinations.

Example: lets say I've got 3 variables named "one", "two" & "three". Each variable can be any value between 1 and 2. This means I have 2 to the power of 3 or a 8 different variable combinations. My list of possible variable combinations would look something like:

```
[
    [one:1,two:1,three:1],
    [one:1,two:1,three:2],
    [one:1,two:2,three:1],
    [one:1,two:2,three:2],
    [one:2,two:1,three:1], 
    [one:2,two:1,three:2],
    [one:2,two:2,three:1],
    [one:2,two:2,three:2]
]
```

I would then run logic against each possible variable combination and this gives me the result of that variable combination. The end result being that I know which variable combination gives me the best result. This works great across smaller variable sets but takes days across larger sets.

Comment: I think you could use Dynamic Programming for this but I could be wrong.

Comment: Can you use gradient descent to search for the best answers instead of guessing and checking?

Comment: Or linear programming depending on the equation you're trying to optimize? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674045/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-programming-optimization-and-a-gradient-de#55674110

Comment: What exactly are you trying to optimize, what is the logic that determines the value of a variable combination? Depending on that, it may or may not be feasible to use some optimization technique.

Comment: I'm optimizing an algorithm with variable parameters which is applied to real world data

Comment: Can you give more info about what the "logic" is for determining the best solution? This is NP-hard in the general case to solve even approximately [Hastad 2001] -- you're essentially optimizing over vertices of a hypercube. DP is also an option IF there's some substructure you can exploit (i.e. a recurrence for expressing solutions). Branch-and-bound will work, but can be as bad as this solution worst-case.